# CSS Background color is taking in safari mac system

Tags: html, css, safari

i have written css for dropdown and i have applied background color on it. its working fine on IE 7,8,9,10 , Chrome, FF , safari (window). but in mac system its not showing background color.

in mac its applying white background.

this is my website url http://www.earlylearninghq.org.uk/ and have look on dropdown beside search box.

this my css code

```
 @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
.selecter .selecter-selected { 
  background-color: #80B83B;
  background: url(http://www.earlylearninghq.org.uk/wp-content/themes/10eight/Search-bar-Arrow.png) no-repeat right 3px center; 
  color: #fff; 
  cursor: pointer; 
  display: block; 
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 0; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  padding: 6px 24px 4px 9px; 
  position: relative; 
  text-overflow: clip; 
  z-index: 2; 
  width: 64px;
  margin-top : -27px;
}
```

}

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove background property from your class. Looks like it is applying two times.

```
  @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
   .selecter .selecter-selected { 
    background-color: #80B83B;
    /*background: url(http://www.earlylearninghq.org.uk/wp-content/themes/10eight/Search-bar-Arrow.png) no-repeat right 3px center;*/ 
    color: #fff; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    display: block; 
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 0; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    padding: 6px 24px 4px 9px; 
    position: relative; 
    text-overflow: clip; 
    z-index: 2; 
    width: 64px;
    margin-top : -27px;
   }
 }
```